# Interfacing bash with awk:

Tags: bash, awk

I am a beginner in awk and was looking at tweaking some bash script at work that interfaces with awk utility to parse the output of some system files. I made my changes based on my understanding and then better sense prevailed, and so I thought I would write a simple test program to try out the same logical pattern. But to my disappointment, the test program didn't work as expected. I am reproducing below the bash script and the awk utility script that I had coded, along with the error that I am getting. Appreciate your thoughts.

```
bash script
-----------

#!/bin/bash

string=$'a\nb\nc\nd\ne'
echo "$string"

awk -v input=${string} -f post.awk < file_input.txt > file_output.txt


awk script
----------

#!/bin/gawk

BEGIN {
  
  getline tmp
  print tmp > $3

}

END{

 print $1 > $3

}
```

In the awk script, I am trying to read the single line `"Only one line"` inside `file_input.txt`, and write it to `file_output.txt` inside the `BEGIN` block. Inside the `END` block, I am trying to write the string passed on command-line to the awk script, to `file_output.txt`.

I get the following output upon running the bash script:

a

b

c

d

```
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file 'c' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

Obviously, I haven't got how awk processes the command-line arguments based on the error. I was assuming that in the line

```
awk -v input=${string} -f post.awk < file_input.txt > file_output.txt

$1 would be input
$2 would be file_input.txt
$3 would be file_output.txt
```

Can someone point out where I have misplaced my assumptions?

TIA

Comment: Can you post an exact set of inputs to your bash script and awk script and also an _exact_ expected output desired. It is unclear at the moment

Comment: In Awk, `$1`, `$2` do not refer to command line arguments. Read up about it. Secondly, redirections are not command arguments anyway! If you invoke a shell script or function like `command < file1 > file2`, there won't be a `$1` and `$2` holding `file1` and `file2`. Rather, the standard input is redirected from `file1` and standard output is redirected to `file2`. The `command` has no arguments.  But anyway, remember that Awk's `$1` and `$2` don't refer to arguments. Awk has an `ARGC` count and `ARGV[]` associative array for command line access.

Comment: In `awk`, `$1` is the content of the first field of the current line.

Comment: please update the question with the (correct) expected output

Comment: You don't need separate BEGIN and END blocks and you [shouldn't use getline for that](http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline), the whole script should be `{print; exit} END{print input}` or `{print; print input; exit}` or similar depending on your unstated requirements for handling an empty file. [edit] your question to show the expected output when the input file is empty so we can help you.

Comment: As the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.". That tool will point out some of your script's problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things wrong with your code:

1. You forget to quote `${string}` leading to the confusing behaviour that awk wants to read the file `c`. Due to the missquoteing, you actually try to execute:

   ```
   $ awk -v input=a b c d -f post.awk < file_input.txt > file_output.txt
   ```

   Here you set the variable `input=a` and try to read 3 files (`b`, `c` and `d`). The file `file_input.txt` has no effect on the awk script, unless you actively process `/dev/stdin` in `post.awk`.
2. You make the mistake and believe that `$n` in the awk code, represents the _n_th argument passed to awk. This is not true. In awk, `$n` represents the n_th field of the current input record.
3. In the `BEGIN` block, there is no input record `$0` defined. Only when an input record is defined, there are fields defined (`$i, i>0`). The `END` block, on the other hand has knowledge of the last input-record read from the input file.

You can define an input record in the BEGIN block by using `getline` as is, but not `getline var` as this does not define `$0`.

So, how can we make this work now.

If you just rely on simple bash, it will work the way you want. That is to say, let bash define, using redirections, what `/dev/stdin` and `/dev/stdout` is of the used command. Example:

```
$ binary < f1 > f2
```

Here, the executable `binary` is executed with `/dev/stdin` pointing to `f1` and `/dev/stdout` pointing to `f2`.

So you can do the same, and write your awk program to just assume default `/dev/stdin` and `/dev/stdout`.

```
# post.awk
BEGIN { getline tmp; print tmp }
END   { print input }
```

and executing this as:

```
$ awk -v input="${string}" -f post.awk file_input.txt > file_output.txt
```

should do the trick.